# Proving general proposition using HPC

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If I have a general Proposition $c$  in HPC + another axiom that $(a \rightarrow b)$.
HPC axioms -
$$1 .a \rightarrow (b \rightarrow a)$$.
$$2. (a \rightarrow (b \rightarrow c))\rightarrow ((a\rightarrow b)\rightarrow (a\rightarrow c)) $$.
$$3. ((\neg b\rightarrow \neg a)\rightarrow (a\rightarrow b)) $$.

And I want to show that a general proposition $c$  is always true.
Should I write a proof using the axioms in HPC that the conclusion is $c$?
(I mean like 1.AXIOM 2.AXIOM .3blabla ... -- > c) or using true tables somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: What is "HPC"? Your textbook's name for a paricular proof system?

Comment: As much as i know it is a well known proof system .

Comment: x @Barak: The _system_ may or may not be well known, but the _name_ you're using for it is not. Names for proof systems are very not standardized, and each author tends to invent his own. If you want the reader of your question to know what you're talking about, you need to _describe_ the proof system in your question, rather than just quoting a pithy name for it.

Comment: Ok, my bad but still i just want to figure what's the principles for showing that each statement can be true in some  proof system. writing a proof using the axioms of the particular system and show that the statement is true ?

Comment: Tho show that a proposition $c$ is a theorem of the theory having $a \to b$ as single (non-logical) axioms you have to write a *derivation*, i.e. a list where every formula either is an axiom (logical and non-logical) or can be inferred by *modus ponens* from previous formulae in the list.

Comment: I couldn't find the right derivation - I changed the question in hope you can help me or give me some hint.

Comment: Fixed that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If (a→b) is an additional axiom, then you can prove 'c' simply by substituting b with c in (a→b), and a with any axiom in (a→b), and then applying detachment to derive c.

Comment: what do u mean by a with any axiom? , just to write a?

Comment: If you have say (a -> b) and you substitute a with axiom t, you obtain (t -> b).  Thus, in order to derive c, if (a - > b) is an axiom, we could say substitute a with (a -> b) and b with c.  This yields ((a -> b) -> c) as a theorem.  Since (a -> b) is an axiom, by detachment we obtain c.