# Show that it is possible to prove every proposition ( $\vdash \gamma$) in the following proof system

Tags: logic

How can I prove that $\vdash\gamma$ in my proof system that has the following axioms and inference rules:

Ax1: $\alpha \rightarrow (\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$

Ax2: $(\alpha \rightarrow (\beta \rightarrow \gamma)) \rightarrow 
((\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \rightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \gamma))$

Ax3: $(\lnot \beta \rightarrow \lnot \alpha) \rightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$

Ax4: $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$

IR: $\frac{\alpha \rightarrow \beta ,  \alpha}{\beta}$ (MP)

It is very hard for me to see the solution, I hope someone could help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [proving general proposition using HPC](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785856/proving-general-proposition-using-hpc).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Axiom 4 allows you to prove any proposition.